# What is a different term for "non-static"?

Tags: java, terminology, definition, xtend

I would like to add a comment saying: `// Here comes the block of non-static members.`
But I would like to avoid negations. So I would like to use another term for "non-static".

To be clear: 
I mean "static" like in `Integer.valueOf("42")` 
I mean "non-static" like in `anObject.equals(otherObject)`

I'm coding in Java / xtend. But I think it is a general question. So it could address any language.

Comment: You'd sometimes call an _instance_ member.

Comment: How about "instance methods"?

Comment: Do you mean variables and  constants?

Comment: @Zabuza The questions is "is there". So if you believe there is no term for this, your proper answer should be "no", not closing...

Comment: Java itself uses the term. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Comment: @dodekja Yes, I mean variables and constants (and methods, too) :)

Comment: @Savior That's good, thank you!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: Good hint, I changed the question (without changing its spirit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write the comment as

```
// Here comes the block of instance members / methods.
```

Comment: methods are also members of the class so I'm not sure if you'd need that separation